# How can one confirm that reported transactions on the exchange actually occur and are not due to wash-trading?

Tags: exchanges, trading, binance, websockets

For instance, if I'm subscribed to binance's websocket trade stream.. and it is reporting trades..  how can one be assured that the trades are actually occuring and not just the exchange trading with itself or generating false data to pump up their volume numbers?